# tf.while_loop strange behavior with tf.concat

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to build a matrix through concatenating elements and reusing the matrix as an input in a tf.while_loop , the output of tf.concat is expected to be a tensor of shape `(x+1,y)` but instead it returns (x+1) tensors of shape `(y,)` which causes the two structures to not have the same nested structure.

Here is a code snippet that recreates the issue:

```
@tf.function(autograph=False)
def cond(a):
    if a.shape[0] != None:
        return tf.less(a.shape[0],5)
    else:
        return tf.constant(True)


def loop():
    ans = tf.while_loop(cond,
                        lambda a: tf.concat([a,tf.zeros((1,5),dtype=tf.float64)],axis=0),
                        loop_vars=[tf.zeros((1,5),dtype=tf.float64)],
                        shape_invariants=[tf.TensorShape((None,5))],parallel_iterations=1)

    return ans
```

Adding a `@tf.function` decorator to the loop simply causes it to freeze without giving an error message or anything of the sort.

Here is the error message without a `@tf.function` decorator :

```
ValueError: The two structures don't have the same nested structure.

First structure: type=list str=[TensorSpec(shape=(1, 5), dtype=tf.float64, name=None)]

Second structure: type=list str=[<tf.Tensor: shape=(5,), dtype=float64, numpy=array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(5,), dtype=float64, numpy=array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])>]
```

I am not quite sure why the function is returning a list of multiple tensors, instead of one tensor with the desired shape.

If I change the axis in `tf.concat` to 1, then the function runs without any problems, even though I am not allowing the second component of the shape to change.

I would appreciate any explanation for why this could be happening, thanks in advance.

Comment: which version of `tensorflow` are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think this didn't happen in some TensorFlow versions, so you might say it's a bug, but technically the error is correct (although the error message hardly points you in the right direction). Both your `loop_vars` and `shape_invariants` arguments are a list, but the value returned by the body function is a tensor, not a list, so the structure of the result does not match. You can fix it by simply converting it into a list:

```py
def loop():
    ans = tf.while_loop(cond,
                        lambda a: [tf.concat([a, tf.zeros((1, 5), dtype=tf.float64)], axis=0)],
                        loop_vars=[tf.zeros((1, 5), dtype=tf.float64)],
                        shape_invariants=[tf.TensorShape((None, 5))], parallel_iterations=1)
    return ans
```

Besides that, your `cond` function is a bit strange, you don't usually need to check whether some shape attribute is `None`, you can simply use [`tf.shape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape) to get the actual shape of the tensor:

```py
@tf.function(autograph=False)
def cond(a):
    return tf.shape(a)[0] < 5
```

In TensorFlow 2.2.0 this gives me a warning about that function being retraced on each call, the reason being that the shape of the parameter `a` is different every time, but you can avoid it passing `experimental_relax_shapes=True` to [`tf.function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function).

In any case, you would be better off if you could use a [`tf.TensorArray`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorArray) to accumulate the results and concatenate at the end only:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.function(autograph=False)
def cond(ta, i):
    return i < 5

def loop():
    # Fixed size is better, use dynamic_size=True otherwise
    ta = tf.TensorArray(tf.float64, size=5, element_shape=(1, 5))
    # Initial element
    ta = ta.write(0, tf.zeros((1, 5), dtype=tf.float64))
    ta, _ = tf.while_loop(cond,
                          lambda ta, i: [ta.write(i, tf.zeros((1, 5), dtype=tf.float64)), i + 1],
                          loop_vars=[ta, 1],
                          shape_invariants=[None, tf.TensorShape(())],
                          parallel_iterations=1)
    ans = ta.concat()
    return ans

a = loop()
```

Although the retracing warning does not go off even with `experimental_relax_shapes=True` in this case.

Comment: You were correct about the usage of `tf.shape` instead of `Tensor.shape`, the error persists without the `@tf.function` decorator, but the function runs fine with it once that change is made. I think the issue is rooted in "static shape" vs "dynamic shape"

Why it remains without `@tf.function()` is unclear to me, but I am not too concerned, since I got the program to run in the end